# JAXB implementation for XML

Tags: xml, jaxb

Lets say I have a xml like this :

```
                                                                    <arg>
                                                                        <brick type="Src" gid="2" path="/INVOIC02/IDOC/EDI_DC40/MANDT">

                                                                        </brick>
                                                                    </arg>
                                                                    <arg pin="1">
                                                                        <brick type="Func" gid="1" fname="const" fns="dflt">

                                                                            <bindings>
                                                                                <param name="value">
                                                                                    <value ext_bind="abcd"/>
                                                                                </param>
                                                                            </bindings>
                                                                        </brick>
                                                                    </arg>
                                                                </brick>
                                                            </arg>
```

Now I am new to JAXB and wanted to know how do I get information about each tag here indicating that the other is a child? The tag names are reappearing and can go to any depth.

Can you guys help?